# Server Error in '/' Application for when cURL with php

Tags: php, xml, curl, request

I'm trying to send XML string to a payment gateway and the XML and the request headers are right, yet when im trying to post the request i get an error server error '/', however, when i used `curl_error($ch)` to understand the error i get "500 internal server error".

this is my XML string

```
$input_xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <VPosMessageContract xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OkUrl>'.$OkUrl.'</OkUrl>
            <FailUrl>'.$FailUrl.'</FailUrl>
            <HashData>'.$HashData.'</HashData>
            <MerchantId>'.$MerchantId.'</MerchantId>
            <SubMerchantId>0</SubMerchantId>
            <BatchID>0</BatchID>
            <CustomerId>'.$CustomerId.'</CustomerId>
            <UserName>'.$UserName.'</UserName>
            <HashPassword>'.$HashedPassword.'</HashPassword>
            <MerchantOrderId>013</MerchantOrderId>
            <InstallmentCount>0</InstallmentCount>
            <Amount>'.$Amount.'</Amount>
            <DisplayAmount>'.$total.'</DisplayAmount>
            <FECAmount>0</FECAmount>
            <FECCurrencyCode>0949</FECCurrencyCode>
            <APIVersion>1.0.0</APIVersion>
            <CardType>'.$cardType.'</CardType>
            <CardNumber>'.$card_number.'</CardNumber>
            <CardExpireDateYear>'.$card_exp_year.'</CardExpireDateYear>
            <CardExpireDateMonth>'.$card_exp_month.'</CardExpireDateMonth>
            <CardCVV2>'.$card_cvc.'</CardCVV2>
            <CardHolderName>'.$card_holder_name.'</CardHolderName>
            <PaymentType>1</PaymentType>
            <DebtId>0</DebtId>
            <TransactionType>Sale</TransactionType>
            <SurchargeAmount>0</SurchargeAmount>
            <SGKDebtAmount>0</SGKDebtAmount>
            <InstallmentMaturityCommisionFlag>0</InstallmentMaturityCommisionFlag>
            <TransactionSecurity>'.$TransactionSecurity.'</TransactionSecurity>
        </VPosMessageContract>';
```

and this is the cURL request

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$input_xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-type: application/xml")); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)){
            $error_msg = curl_error($ch);}
        curl_close($ch);
```

the full response that i get is

```
Server Error in '/..' Application.
Runtime Error
    Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

    Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>

    Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` means that there is an issue on the server you are sending your XML too. Do you have access to this server and/or can have a look at the logs? If you are using a third-party API, maybe there is another hint in the documentation, e.g. your XML structure is wrong.

Comment: I did everything like the third-party documentation, yet the demo code they were using was `asp.net` and the website I'm working on is in PHP and so they didn't know how to help.

Comment: Instead of posting your XML file including the `PHP` variables, can you please `echo $input_xml;` in your code and post the result (after removing sensitive information if applicable, of course), here? Maybe the XML is wrong.

Comment: i validated the XML using [link](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator) and it shows its 100% valid

Comment: Check what `$result` contains, there might be a more descriptive error message in the response body.

Comment: i added it to the post, @CBroe

Comment: <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off". Then check the result again. After that it should show you the real error.

Comment: I don’t think this is referring to the API consumer’s part here, but to the settings on the API provider’s server. Looks to me like they have not set their end up to respond with proper API error messages, but this is just “crashing” on their end. I think you will need to contact them to look into the issue from their end first of all.